# PHP rewriting URL to remove .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a project where I decided to get rid of the .php extension from the URL of my app. I am successful using the htaccess code given below. But the problem is, the page still loads using .php extension if typed manually or loaded from the history.

My current .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I want it to always load with `www.example.com/dashboard` except `www.example.com/dashboard.php` even if dashboard.php is manually typed.

UPDATED .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dateapp/
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+).php$ $1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,END]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add redirect as first rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+).php$ /$1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,END]
```

You have to use `END` flag instead of `L` otherwise the redirects will end in infinite loop. This will work if the .htaccess is in your webroot folder.

In case you have .htaccess in 'folder' subfolder you will have to add `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+).php$ $1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,END]
```

Comment: it takes me to the root URL i.e., localhost/dashboard.php but my file is in localhost/folder/dashboard.php . Also, its not removing the extension.

Comment: Do you have the .htaccess in webroot or in the 'folder' subfolder?

Comment: @AurazoScript I've added a version for the .htaccess in subfolder instead of webroot.

Comment: I replaced "folder" with my folder name but when trying to access the page using the .php extension it quits and says "This page isn't redirecting properly".

Comment: @AurazoScript can you add the edited htaccess to you question? I've tested both variants and they worked fine for me.

Comment: Updated the question. Please have a look. However, if its working for you then why not for me? Did you check by manually adding .php extension in the end? Because it does open without .php extension well but this problem is happening after adding the .php extension to the end of the page name like dashboard.php

Comment: @AurazoScript that's exactly how i've tested it. When i typed the url as /folder/script.php the browser got redirected to /folder/script and then displayed the proper result. Maybe you can try adding `rewrite:trace5` into `LogLevel` directive in `httpd.conf` and restart apache. Then you should be able to see how the rules are applied in apache's error.log.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code in `dateapp/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dateapp/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```